# First time running a ruby app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run a Rails app on my Snow Leopard Mac. I never worked with Ruby or Rails before, so any hint is welcome.

In terminal I went to the folder of the app, and ran `rails server`
and received the following error:

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

and `database.yml` has `adapter: mysql2` for all environments. I already ran `bundle install`, and from running `gem list` I got:

```
mysql2 (0.3.11)
```

My gem environment is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.17
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I have been going around with this for more than last two hours with no luck so far.

Comment: Try running "gem list -d", to see where the gems are installed to.  I don't know that thats the problem, but it might shed some light on it and lead to a solution.

Comment: make sure `mysql` bin is available in your `$PATH` before you install the gem and everything should be fine.

Comment: what does `rvm list` give you?

Comment: @ScottS  gem list -d gives me:  http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2
    Installed at: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3
    A simple, fast Mysql library for Ruby, binding to libmysql

Comment: @macek the $PATH of mysql is the one mentioned above, isnt it?

Comment: @JohnnyGrass
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: @JohnnyGrass i got the same results with running rvm list: rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default